# не работают стили при итерации react tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind

я хотел сделать что-то вроде столбцов с подписями, но он не ставит необходимую мне высоту.

моя ошибка видимо кроется здесь h-[${ day.amount }px], но я абсолютно не понимаю почему в консоли этого свойства абсолютно нет, пытаюсь исправить эту ошибку довольно долго и поэтому буду рад если поможете, если что-то нужно будет ещё я предоставлю.

```
import React from 'react'
import { IDay } from '../models/IDay'

interface Days {
    days: IDay[]
}


const Content = ( { days } : Days) => {

    // console.log(days)

    return (
        <div className='w-96 h-[400px] rounded-xl bg-white m-auto absolute top-36 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 p-4'>
            <h2 className='mb-10'>Spending - Last 7 days</h2>
            <ul className='flex w-full justify-between items-end'>
                { days.map(day => {
                    return (
                        <li key={ day.amount } className={ ` w-1/7 flex-col justify-center h-[${ day.amount }px]` }>
                            <span className={ `h-full w-full flex bg-red-400 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-400` }></span>
                            <p  className='w-full ml-2'>{ day.day }</p>
                        </li>
                        )
                }) }
            </ul>

            <span className='flex w-full h-[2px] mt-10 bg-pink-100'></span>
            <p></p>
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Content
```

Comment: Т.е. в вашем `console.log(days)` нет ключа amount?

Comment: нет, в стилях нет класса со свойством heigth

Comment: Ну так у вас класс называется, допустим, h-[600px]. Он у вас в стилях то есть? Какой класс(с каким названием, для примера, вы хотите там увидеть?

Comment: h-[600px] и любые другие стили он отображает, а если написать подобным образом h-[${ day.amount }px] то он отказывается работать, я хочу чтобы высота изменялась с помощью amount которая хранится в другом месте

Comment: то-есть в классах вот это есть h-[${ day.amount }px], а стилей нет

Comment: Брр... выведи в консоль твой day внутри map и какие стили в строке формируются?

Comment: {
    "day": "mon",
    "amount": 17.45
}

Comment: А строка с классами какая формируется?

Comment: .justify-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.w-1\/7 {
    width: 13%;
}

Comment: w-1/7 flex-col justify-center h-[17.45px] - это его классы

Comment: Можно из HTML тега class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind не работает с динамическими классами. Он читает текст как есть. Т.е. в Вашем случае h-[${ day.amount }px]. А такого класса нет. Соответственно и в основной файл css ничего не пишется.
С помощью tailwind не получится сделать то, что Вы хотите.